# Kotlin - Handling apostrophe character while creating a string for SQL

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a string to query a SQL database. The query is something like below:

Works fine:

```
Select * from TableName where item = 'Room A' OR item = 'Room B'
```

Doesn't work due to 's:

```
Select * from TableName where item = 'Room A' OR item = 'Room's B'
```

I am getting the values Room A or Room B from a json object and below is the sample code for it.

```
expression = "$keyName = '${jsonObject.valueName}'"
```

How can I escape the 's in the value?

Comment: Your SQL API (`SQLiteDatabase`, Room, etc.) should handle that escaping for you (e.g., `SQLiteDatabase` and positional parameters). How are you communicating with this database?

Comment: Does `\'` work?

Comment: @CommonsWare - One of my internal library at work is communicating with the DB and looks like they are not handling it. I am just passing the string as an input to their API.

Comment: @JoshuaFeltimo - Will try that next. Right now am trying to replace ' with "'" to check if it will work.

Comment: @JoshuaFeltimo - \' didn't work for me

Comment: @tech_human Replace only the aphostrophe in the name of the table with double quotes 'Room''s B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced "'" with "''" to make it work, but I am not sure which other characters could break SQL.

Comment: it will work, it only applies to the tables name, and you will have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace only the aphostrophe in the name of the table with double quotes, from 'Room's B' to 'Room''s B' and you will get the query from your table :

```
Select * from TableName where item = 'Room A' OR item = 'Room''s B'
```

I have experienced something similar, because i had the name "`Secton´s X`" in one of my tables

[image]